# Get the actual value of free memory is sun sparc

Tags: bash, sun, sparc

I am trying to get the current (not the average) free memory size of SUN SPARC remote server, but I don't have the permission to use `free -m` command or `prtconf`. So, I used command `vmstat 2` and the result is
kthr      memory            page            disk          faults      cpu

```
r b w   swap  free  re  mf pi po fr de sr vc vc vc vc   in   sy   cs us sy id

0 0 0 46981864 20824288 311 416 51 1 1 0 0 27 6  0 18 16070 33290 17580 12 2 87

0 0 0 45534984 9138264 127 405 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0 32 17427 45040 20877 25 2 73

0 0 0 45534984 9138072 208 510 0 0 0 0  0  7  0  0  0 14544 35758 17416 23 2 75

0 0 0 45534984 9138072 96 324 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0 63 6443 11683 5701 11 1 89
```

and `vmstat| awk '{print $5}'` and the result is 20824288  which is the average not the current value ,so how to get the actual value ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use command like:

```
vmstat 1 3|tail -1 |awk '{print $5}'
```

The idea is to exec `vmstat` 3 times (the first execution get average values from the start of the system), get last line and extract free memory value.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use top's output:

```
top | awk '/free mem$/{print $5}'
```

Output (example):

```
3201M
```